# Oracle SQL: Grouping and allocating data based on 3 criteria

Tags: sql, plsql, logic, oracle-sqldeveloper

Quite a long-winded question:

As a hypothetical situation i am trying to split a table of data between two companies: OPM, MON.

```
|NAME       |ACCOUNT    |BALANCE    |COMPANY
_______________________________________________
|SMITH      |11111      |100        |
|SMITH      |11111      |150        |
|HUNTER     |11121      |200        |
|HUNTER     |11131      |250        |
|LITTLE     |11141      |300        |
|RIDLEY     |11151      |300        |
|RIDLEY     |11151      |100        |
|ARMSTRONG  |11161      |150        |
|ARMSTRONG  |11171      |150        |
|HENRY      |11181      |100        |
```

There are several scenario's with the customer data. 1. Customer has two accounts, both have the same account number, but with different balances. 2. Customer has two accounts, different account numbers and different balances. 3. Customer has one account, one account number, one balance.

I need to write out logic in SQL / PL-SQL that enables the data to fulfill an allocation to either of the two different companies and that also follows rules.

1. A customer, regardless of how many accounts, must be allocated to the same company.
2. The value of accounts must be roughly equal.
3. The volume of accounts must be roughly equal.

I accept the limitation in the data i have provided, but the logic must be extrapolated to larger datasets. What is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: Two accounts, with the same account number?!? I hope you're not working for my bank...

Comment: What did you try? Can you share the code you have?

Comment: Hi, the two account numbers would be different products in the same account, i have left a distinct product out for ease here. I have written code however the logic is harder to figure out in this case for us. I have tried to split the accounts numerous ways and in different priorities i.e.(customer,balance,volume) however as the accounts change each week, the logic does not stay true. As Gordon mentions below it seems to be a bin-packing problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a bin-packing problem, and this is generally hard.  However, you simply state that the two groups need to be approximately equal.  So, I would suggest adding up the balances for each customer and taking a stratified sample:

```
select name, balance,
       (case when mod(seqnum, 2) = 0 then 'Company1' else 'Company2' end)
from (select name, sum(balance) as balance,
             row_number() over (order by balance) as seqnum
      from table t
      group by name
     ) n
```

Note:  this is an approximate approach.  It puts half the accounts in each group, and they should have similar total balances.  There are many cases where this will not produce an optimal solution (such as when one "name" has very large balances compared to everyone else), but it might be good enough.

Comment: Hi Gordon, unfortunately the account number is a key part to play in this as it would direct any incoming information to the correct part of the account. Your description as a bin-packing problem however seems to have hit the nail on the head.